# Re-calculate formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Sub with variable "porcen" like this:

```
Dim porcen as Integer
porcen = Cells(1, 1).Value
```

After some calculations I have 3 variables. Var1, Var2 and Var3 depend on the variable porcen.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(IF(R[" & var1 & "]C="""","""",((COUNTIF(R[" & var1+ 1 + var2 & "]C:R[" & var1 + 1 & "]C,R[" & var1 & "]C))-(COUNTIF(R[" & var3 & "]C:R[-5]C,R[" & var1 & "]C)))/(" & var2 & ")))"
```

I don't know why if I change the value in cell(1,1), the result of the formula remains unchanged.

I wish that when I change the value in Cell(1,1) the result also change.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that you simply left out the code that sets `Var1`, `Var2` & `Var3` based on the value of `porcen`, then `Gary's Student`'s answer would be correct. You have to put the code you wrote (or better yet, a call to it), then the `Worksheet_OnChange` event for that worksheet. If you don't, then Excel doesn't know to trigger a call to your function when the value of `Cells(1,1)` changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change in value in **Cells(1,1)**, you must re-calculate *porcen, var1, var2, var3* to reflect that change.  You can do this automatically with an event macro.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *porcen* is a long, string or maybe even a variant that gets assigned the *Value* from A1 (aka Cells(1, 1)). If you want to lock porcen to A1, declare it as a range type variable and `Set` it to A1.

```
dim porcen as range
set porcen = cells(1, 1)

' do stuff with porcen.Value or porcen.Row or porcen.Column, etc just like a cell

' some say you don't have to do the next step before exiting the sub. I do it anyways.
set porcen = nothing
```